# Generate Table with colspan According json data dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Hello Everyone I stuck in a problem to generate desired html table with colspan according to my json data .For example my json array list is like below

```
[0]{category:Math, Type: P, BookName: Book1 ,Count:2}
[1]{category:Math, Type: P, BookName: Book2 ,Count:3}
[2]{category:Math, Type: T, BookName: Book3 ,Count:1}
[3]{category:Math, Type: T, BookName: Book4,Count:2}
[4]{category:Biology, Type: T, BookName: Book1 ,Count:2}
[5]{category:Biology, Type: p, BookName: Book1 ,Count:10}
```

Here I have books with category their type practical(p),theoretical(T),Book name,and count ,what i am trying to do generate a table from this data .The table column format will be like category ,Type ,Name and count ,I attached a drawing image below ,which i want to generate ,but i dont know how to do that

[image]

Is that even possible by javascript/jquery easily ???

I tried something but seems not fruitful it seems like i am far away from the solution

what i tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.each(data, function (key, item) {
$('table#2 tbody tr td').each(function(){
var value = $(this).html();
if(value.indexOf("Math") !== -1){ 
    $(this).attr("colspan", 2);
  $(this).next("td").remove(); 
 }
});
});
});
```

I need to show my data like the image i attached if possible .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your data into a representation that goes through like - category->Types of that category-> Book, count of that type.

```
let dataMap = new Map();
let totalLevels = 4;
for(let d of data){
    if(!dataMap.get(d.category)){
    dataMap.set(d.category, {totalCount:0, types: new Map()});
  }
  if(!dataMap.get(d.category).types.get(d.Type)){
    dataMap.get(d.category).types.set(d.Type, []);
  }
  dataMap.get(d.category).types.get(d.Type).push({'bookName' : d.BookName, 'Count' : d.Count});
  dataMap.get(d.category).totalCount++;
}
```

Push each row to an array.

```
    let rows = []
for(let i = 0; i<totalLevels;i++){
    rows.push([])
}
for (var [key, value] of dataMap) {
    rows[0].push(`<th colspan=${value.totalCount} id=${key}>${key}</th>`);
  for(var [typeKey,typeValue] of value.types){
    rows[1].push(`<td colspan=${typeValue.length}>${typeKey}</td>`);
    for(let o of typeValue){
        rows[2].push(`<td>${o.bookName}</td>`);
      rows[3].push(`<td>${o.Count}</td>`);
    }
  }
}
```

And then finally append the rows to table.

```
for(row of rows){
    $('table').append(`<tr>${row}</tr>`);
}
```

Here's a demo - https://jsfiddle.net/znxhkm7g/

Comment: Thank you so much i tried your code but its not working in my script tag showing error i dont know how to process it or convert it to jquery , can you please convert    
 for (var [key, value] of dataMap) {
    rows[0].push(`<th colspan=${value.totalCount} id=${key}>${key}</th>`);
  for(var [typeKey,typeValue] of value.types){
    rows[1].push(`<td colspan=${typeValue.length}>${typeKey}</td>`);
    for(let o of typeValue){
        rows[2].push(`<td>${o.bookName}</td>`);
      rows[3].push(`<td>${o.Count}</td>`);
    }
  }
}       This portion to jquery ??? @Jason

Comment: That code block is native javascript. It shouldn't have any problem with running that. What is the error?

Comment: Thank you very much I managed to convert your code ,the Maping logic helped me a lot Thank you very much .If further help needed i will ask you again.